# sbt UnknownHostException repo.scala-sbt.org

Tags: sbt, nexus

Since bintray decommissionning we have no more repository for example sbt-play-ebean

this is my file plugins.sbt

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.2")
```

and the compilation error

> download error: Caught java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.scala-sbt.org (repo.scala-sbt.org) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-play-ebean/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/5.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml

we don't know where the sbt repo is !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following repository URL in your sbt configuration:

```
https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/sbt-plugin-releases/
```

However the one you are already using should work fine as well, it does a redirection to the one above.

Comment: yes it was also certificate and open port on our proxy side